# Is there any way to use (embed) Gmail - Yahoo on your website?

Tags: gmail, yahoo

*I'm not talking about something like cURLs or SMTP server*

I have an stupid idea that instead of building a upload system, user can email for me with attach file.
So I think if gmail (or yahoo..) has an API to embed the SEND Mail page with a free account to my webpage so that all the user can use it?

Sorry for my bad English :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either simply provide an email address and ask that people send emails to it with their attachment(s), or create a HTML form which allows users to upload a file which is processed by CGI. I use [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) on the front end, and a Perl CGI script to process the results.